# Take data from a .xml file to a text

Tags: linux

So I have a XML file that contains a lot of data. My task is to extract the 'name' and 'description' information from the XML file so it reads out. I have been messing with it for a while, and I got half way there.

The way the data that I need to extract in the XML file looks like is
`<name> Some Name</name>`
 and the data that is in the description is 
    `<description> The Description </description>`

What I have done is extract all the description to a text file, but I know I am doing this the hard/not efficient way. Any ideas?

Also, if I could add some detail to help describe what I am doing, I can do so! Hopefully I described it efficiently though.

Comment: Add a sample of the xml file as it isn't clear from your description. If possible, also give the code for what you have done so far.

Comment: Is a programming solution a possibility? On linux, you could write a c# /mono app where you run an xpath query to select nodes and write out their contents.

Comment: Sorry, I thought he code snip was in there. I was editing as you commented :p

Comment: Nathan, do you have a link to a guide or anything that could help with that? It sounds interesting.

Comment: I agree with @Nathan Wheeler. It should only be a small amount of code to select the nodes you want with XPath.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: So, I write a Xpath code file, and then use my c# code to run it?

Comment: Please see my answer with a link to a tutorial below. The XPath will be in the c# code.

Comment: If the answer is useful please upvote and mark as correct answer. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments in question, create a C# application which uses XPath to extract the nodes you are interested in.

A good tutorial to follow:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333